# Proving that $p \implies q$ and $\neg p \implies \neg q$ are not equivalent, without using truth tables

Tags: logic

How do I prove that
$$p \implies q$$
and
$$\neg p \implies \neg q$$
are **not** equivalent?

I have to prove this using expression manipulation and not truth tables.

Comment: Expression manipulation is only valid because of truth tables

Answer (score 1):

$0$ indicates "false", and $1$ indicates "true".

$\forall p,q\in\{0, 1\}(p\implies q\iff\neg p\implies\neg q)$

$\implies(1\implies 0\iff\neg 1\implies\neg 0)$

$\iff(1\implies 0\iff\ 0\implies1)$

$\iff(0\iff\ 1)$

$\iff 0$

The statement is false.

Comment: That is a truth table. You've just left out the rows you didn't need.

Comment: If you extend the definition of a "truth table" to this, then there IS no way to prove that the statement is false without using a truth table. This is the case precisely because the statement is false for SOME values of $P$ and $Q$, rather than all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $q=\neg p$ we get
$$(p \Rightarrow \neg p) \Leftrightarrow (\neg p \Rightarrow \neg \neg p)$$
$$(p \Rightarrow \neg p) \Leftrightarrow (\neg p \Rightarrow p)$$
$$(\neg p \lor \neg p) \Leftrightarrow (\neg \neg p \lor p)$$
$$(\neg p \lor \neg p) \Leftrightarrow (p \lor p)$$
$$\neg p \Leftrightarrow p$$
which is clearly false.

Tautologies used: $(p \Rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow (\neg p \lor q)$, $\neg \neg p \Leftrightarrow p$, $(p \lor p) \Leftrightarrow p$.